# Proof - form of mean value theorem for vector valued function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Can someone show me the proof of this form of the mean value theorem for vector valued functions?

Let $f:R^n \rightarrow R^n$ be a function of class $C^1$ and $a,b\in R^n$, than there exists some $d\in R^n : a<d<b$ such that

$(b-a)\cdot (f(b)-f(a))=(b-a)\cdot (f'(d)(b-a)) $

where $\cdot$ is a dot product

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is $f'(d)$ a matrix? The notation is slightly unusual.

Comment: What does $a<d<c$ _mean_ for $a,b\in\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the theorem 3.10 of *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher:

> **Mean value theorem in integral form:** let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces over $\Bbb R$, $X\subset E$ and suppose that $f\in C^1(X,F)$. Then
>
> $$f(y)-f(x)=\int_0^1\partial f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)\,\mathrm dt\tag1$$
>
> such that $[\![x,y]\!]\subset X$, with $[\![x,y]\!]:=\{x+t(y-x):t\in[0,1]\}$.

Setting $\varphi(t):=\langle v,f(x+t(y-x))\rangle$ for some $v\in F$ and applying the dot product $\langle v,\cdot\rangle$ to both sides of $(1)$ we get

$$\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\int_0^1\varphi'(t)\,\mathrm dt\tag2$$

because

$$\left\langle v,\int_0^1\partial f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)\,\mathrm dt\right\rangle=\int_0^1\langle v,\partial f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)\rangle\,\mathrm dt$$

cause $\langle v,\cdot\rangle$ is a linear function. Thus from $(2)$ we can use the MVT for real valued functions, that is

$$\varphi(1)-\varphi(0)=\varphi'(\eta)$$

for some $\eta\in [0,1]$, what is equivalent to the stated MVT of the question.