# One question regarding the jacobian of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Can anyone help me understand the following formula? Is there a way to think about this geometrically?

$$\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x) + \int_0^{1}\nabla^2f(x+tp)pdt$$ where t is between 0 and 1.

Note: $f:R^n \rightarrow R$. So x and p in the equation are $R^n$ vectors.

Comment: sorry, my previous comment was not totally right. It is a consequence of the mean value theorem in integral form, take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2536716/173262)