# Show that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ preserves distances if $|Df(p)(u)| = |u|$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth map such that $|Df(p)(u)| = |u|$ for all $p, u \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f$ preserves distances, i.e. $|f(p) - f(q)| = |p - q|$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I've already shown that $Df(p)$ is an isomorphism and a linear isometry, and therefore $f$ is a diffeomorphism. How do I go from here to showing that $f$ preserves distances?

Comment: because $\Bbb R^n$ is convex you can use the [mean value theorem in integral form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536648/proof-form-of-mean-value-theorem-for-vector-valued-function/2536716#2536716) and the result is immediate.

Comment: @Masacroso: This theorem only gives you  $|f(p)-f(q)|\leq |p-q|$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$, $q\in{\mathbb R}^n$ be given,  let
$$\gamma: \quad t\mapsto x(t):=(1-t)p+t q\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)$$
be the segment connecting $p$ with $q$, and let
$$\gamma':\quad t\mapsto g(t):=f\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 1)$$
be its image curve. Then $g'(t)=df\bigl(x(t)\bigr).x'(t)$
and therefore $|g'(t)|=|x'(t)|$, by assumption on $df$. It follows that  $$|f(p)-f(q)|\leq  L(\gamma')=L(\gamma)=|p-q|\ ,$$ whatever $p$, $q\in{\mathbb R}^n$.

On the other hand, our $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, hence each point $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ which is bijectively mapped onto a neighborhood $V$ of $p'=f(p)$. Points $q'$ nearby $p'$ can be joined to $p'$ with a segment that has a preimage in $U$, so that (applying the above argument to the local $f^{-1}$) we now also have $|p-q|=|f^{-1}(p')-f^{-1}(q')|\leq |p'-q'|$. This shows that $f$ is a local isometry, and allows to conclude that the image of a line is straight all the way. That should suffice.

Comment: @Masacroso: See my edit.